# dot instead of comma as thousand separator

Tags: ls, locale, size

I read about `--blocksize` for `ls` to get a thousands separator.

However my computer gives me dot (`.`) and not comma (`,`):

```
$ ls -l --block-size="'1"
total 11.893.190.656
-rw------- 1 carlah users  1.081.192.448 Apr 16  2013 D1.vdi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 carlah users             37 Apr  3  2012 interface.txt
-rw------- 1 carlah users     86.052.864 Apr 16  2012 D2.vdi
drwx------ 2 carlah users          4.096 Apr 16  2012 Snapshots/
-rw------- 1 carlah users 10.725.925.376 Apr 16  2012 Vista.vdi
```

I tried `LC_NUMERIC=en_US ls -l --block-size="'1"` to change that but that did just remove the dots not turn them into commas. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at your settings with:

```
echo $LC_NUMERIC
```

and then try something like what you have there, like:

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" ls -l --block-size="'1"
```

Comment: Thx, it worked. But I had en_DK.utf-8, why would that be set like that?

Comment: `en_DK.UTF-8` tives 24 hour clock, but that is for LC_TIME setting.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the `en_US` locale is available at your system.

Use `locale -a` to list available locales and `/etc/locale.gen` to configure.
(Be aware that your distribution might have its own tool for managing locales.)

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=C ls -l --block-size="'1" linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso 
-rw------- 1 michas users 1252147200 24. Dez 00:12 linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE ls -l --block-size="'1" linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso 
-rw------- 1 michas users 1.252.147.200 24. Dez 00:12 linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US ls -l --block-size="'1" linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso 
-rw------- 1 michas users 1,252,147,200 24. Dez 00:12 linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso
$ locale -a
C
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
deutsch
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
german
POSIX
$
```